# Use an complement address?

Tags: here-api

I would like to know what is the correct way to add the complement of an address in the API, today I am using it as follows:

Rua Sebastião Gouveia S/N, lote 34 quadra 26, Km 32, Nova Iguaçu - RJ, 26298644, Brasil

`https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}&countryfocus=BRA&country=Brasil&street=Rua Sebastião Gouveia&housenumber=S/N&city=Nova Iguaçu&district=Km 32&postalcode=26298644&state=RJ`

> "S/N" -> No number

I need to add this value "lot 34 block 26" as a complement, how to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complement address can be passed in additionaldata attribute. please refer following documentation to get details about the parameters.

> https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/resource-geocode.html